# Why are PhDs the most common doctoral degree?

Tags: phd, degree

I have heard many people say they have a PhD in a certain area.  For nearly all of my life,  I thought a PhD was simply a doctorate,  and I didn't know that it had anything to do with philosophy.

There are many doctoral degrees, why are PhD's the most popular doctoral degrees by a long shot?

Comment: _"There are many doctoral degrees"_ ... To clarify the question, can you provide examples of these other types of degrees that are common in your area?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*This answer suffered a Major Revision!*

---

A Ph.D. is an academic doctoral degree and have nothing to do with philosophy nowadays.

From Wikipedia:

> *In the context of the Doctor of Philosophy and other similarly titled degrees, the term "philosophy" does not refer to the field or academic discipline of philosophy, but is used in a broader sense in accordance with its original Greek meaning, which is "love of wisdom".*

People often refers to an academic doctorate as a Ph.D., even when the official title in their university/country is different of Doctor of Philosophy. The reason beyond its popularity is because a Ph.D. is a title traditionally conceded in countries with anglo-saxonic language and since the common language in the academia is English we often "translate" our titles to the equivalent in English.

I have recently learned with @Pete L. Clark that there are different types of doctorates in the US that give the same legal statute as an academic doctorate, but with different structure and requisites from a doctorate in Science. The example that he used was the Doctor of Arts (D.A.), a title that gives equivalent rights as a Ph.D. in which concerns teaching and research in universities.

My previous misunderstanding was due to the structure of high level education that I am used to in Portugal and Brazil. In both countries Therapists, Physicians, Lawyers and others do not have a doctoral degree. In Portugal a physician have Master's degree in Health Science or a 6 years pre-bologna *licenciatura* degree (undergraduate degree). If a physician/lawyer/therapists wants to have a doctoral degree here they need to engage in a minimum 3 years doctoral course, publish articles and defend an original thesis.

For a historical insight and more complete overview, please read [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy) and [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorate).

I'm sorry for the previous wrong answer. I think the question is too wide and depends highly on which country we are talking about. I assumed things about the doctoral degrees on the US that are not true.

Edit: Of course that there are many different ways to refer to an academic doctorate depending on the country the title is emitted. The point is: they are all equivalent. A German Doktorgrad is equivalent to a Ph.D. in the UK and to a Doutoramento/Doutorado in Portugal/Brazil, etc. In the other way researchers would not be able to work across the borders.

Comment: This seems untrue, ish. In common communication, yes, a *doctorate* refers to a PhD, but hearing it applied to MD is not uncommon. And technically, various other doctorates exist: JD (lawyer), DMD (dentist), DSD (dental surgeon), OD (optometrist), DVM (vet), PsyD (psychologist, though it’s relatively new and a PhD in psychology is the more common doctorate in that field), *etc.* The thrust of the question, I think, is why so many fields congregate under PhD instead of each having their own _D, like some of the above.

Comment: The [history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy#Medieval_and_early_modern_Europe) in the linked article is the relevant part. Traditionally, a university degree was either a professional degree or a degree in the arts/philosophy. Fields of study have evolved, but many of the old titles remain.

Comment: @KRyan These titles are specific from some countries like US and they are not equivalent to a Ph.D or a doctorate. Physicians and Lawyers in Brazil and Portugal are called doctors only because the tradition of using it as a pronoun to express respect. In general physicians have a master's degree in health science.

Comment: This answer is unfortunately wrong: Even Wikipedia states in the first paragraph of its "[Doctorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Doctorate&oldid=816071374)" article that "There are a variety of doctoral degrees, with the most common being the Doctor of Philosophy (PhD), which is awarded in many different fields, ranging from the humanities to the scientific disciplines". There are MDs, D.Phil,  D.Eng, German-style D. rer. nat. etc.

Comment: @errantlinguist The point is: there are many different ways to call a **real** doctorate at doctoral level depending on the country where it is emitted. However they are all the same title and equivalent across the borders. A German Doktorgrad is equivalent to a Ph.D in the UK and to a Doutorado in Portugal. Read the second paragraph of the article you referred, a MD is not equivalent to a doctorate.

Comment: @TheDoctor No, you are again wrong. Just because "doctor" in English sounds like "Doutorado" in Portuguese **does not mean they are interchangeable**: Holders of a *Doutorado* are doctors but not all doctors hold a *Doutorado*. Moreover, this has **nothing** to do with countries: The UK has PhDs, D.Phils, D.Eng, **which are all doctorates but are not equivalent**. I'm now downvoting because you don't seem to understand the differences and are strongly arguing that there are none, which is dangerous to others.

Comment: @errantlinguist So please, answer clarifying the difference between a D.Phil and a Ph.D. Even the University of Oxford says that they are the same title: https://www.sociology.ox.ac.uk/faq/dphil-faq.html .

Comment: @TheDoctor The difference is that you can get a D.Phil from Oxford but not a PhD. Stop looking for low-hanging fruit: See [the Doctor of Engineering degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Engineering), which is not even functionally equivalent like D.Phil and PhD are.

Comment: @errantilinguist They have no practical differences. From the article you referenced: "since 1992 some British universities have introduced the Engineering Doctorate, abbreviated as "EngD", which is instead a research doctorate and regarded in the UK as equivalent to a PhD."

Comment: @TheDoctor yes, they do. Read the article. "while research toward the D.Eng. is applied, rather than the basic, fundamental research in a Ph.D." Even your example *Doktorgrad* is wrong: There are many *Doktorgrad* titles in Germany such as D.-Ing, D. rer. nat. Delete your answer because it is wrong and misleading and could even get people sued (you can't call yourself a PhD for every single kind of doctorate, only as a translation of certain ones).

Comment: @errantlinguist The difference is only on the field of research, as I have said before. In many countries there are only one name for the doctoral degrees, independent if it is applied or fundamental research. I'm not convinced that my answer is wrong and I think you have not understood my point. Flag my answer and ask for a community intervention if you think it is misleading. I will not delete it. Now I need to work and I will not continue with this useless discussion.

Comment: 1) PhD was originally a German degree. Its usage has evolved in different ways in different countries. 2) The research doctorates granted by faculties of medicine in some countries can be either DMedSci or PhD, depending on whether the recipient is also MD.

Comment: It is generally accepted in the US that MDs, DDS and certain related medical degrees are doctoral degrees. Some have even made that argument for JDs. They are not *research* doctorates, but that does not make them cease being doctoral degrees.

Comment: -1 because this answer is factually wrong. PhDs are not the only kind of doctorates.

Comment: Everyone, I'm not usually the sort of person to ask this, but I'd like everyone to downvote this, seeing as the answerer has acknowledged that the answer is dangerously misleading and has not even amended it; The only reason I can see why they are defending their answer as it stands is because of how many upvotes it has.

Comment: If MDs are equivalent to Master's degrees in Europe then what do European doctors get??

Comment: @errantlinguist where I have acknowledged it? :)

Comment: @TheDoctor your arguments keep getting weaker and weaker after being proved wrong again and again. Everything you write is wrong, and then you add qualifying information, e.g. "the difference is only on the field of research". That is everything *but* an explicit acknowledgement; If you were academically honest, you would admit your original answer is wrong and delete the answer in order to save others from potentially getting hurt. Instead, you keep throwing out excuses and new, weak arguments.

Comment: @Azor-ahai They get a master's degree in Health Science. If they want to have a doctoral degree they need to engage in an academic doctoral program, publish articles in peer-review journals and defend an original doctoral thesis. The same thing for lawyers. They are still called doctors by the general public, because it is the historically pronoun of treatment for those professionals.

Comment: [Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128957/260312).

Comment: Agreed that it is not worth flagging, but: yes, you are simply incorrect that "PhD" and "doctorate" are synonymous.  To see this it is enough to exhibit a doctoral degree that is not a PhD.  For this see e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Arts.  One of my colleagues has this degree and has a job for which a "doctoral degree" is a requirement: here is is webpage http://www.math.uga.edu/directory/michael-klipper, which has a link to his CV, in which you can see that he has a DA rather than a PhD.

Comment: @Pete Thank you for this example. Now I see that I was wrong. I've never heard about such  title as equivalent to a doctoral degree, with all the legal consequences of allowing to pursue an academic job as professor. Here in Portugal this title does not exist in arts, we have academic doctoral programs in arts with the same structure and demands of a doctoral program in science. Do you think I should delete my answer?

Comment: @TheDoctor how is the "Doctor of Arts" comparison any different to the "Doctor of Engineering" example, which you refused to accept?-- even the wording is similar: "While the Ph.D. is the most common doctoral degree in the United States, the U.S. Department of Education and the National Science Foundation recognize numerous research-oriented doctoral degrees such as the D.A. as "equivalent", and do not discriminate between them."

Comment: @errantlinguist Giving you the benefit of the doubt that you're genuinely asking: Your overall rhetoric is ineffective here because it reeks of elitism and dismissive bias, with just a hint of sycophantic melodrama. Pete's references clearly support the validity of his claims with concrete examples, while the purpose and applicability of your reference is unclear and gives an incoherent *impression* of frustratedly grasping for an emotionally appealing but ultimately flimsy argument. At least, those appear to be the main differences...

Comment: Emitted or omitted?

Comment: Downvoted, fully agreeing that this is a blatantly wrong answer. (Another example of a non-Ph.D. doctorate is the "[D.V.Sc.](https://www.uoguelph.ca/registrar/calendars/graduate/2013-2014/gradprog/vets-dvsc.shtml)", by the way.)

Comment: I have edit the answer based on this discussion. I hope that now it is acceptable.

Comment: Note that in Brazil, the top degree is called a *doutorado*, but in Portugal, it's called a *doutoramento* (anyone with an undergraduate degree is already style *Dr./Dra.*)

Answer (score 12):

PhDs are more common because PhDs come from all fields and most countries.
To talk in broad strokes (I suggest looking into each of these points, e.g. in wikipedia for more details.)

Lets break our doctorates into 3 kinds:

### Research Doctorates

These are given for doing research, and intended to train researchers.

- Doctorate of Philosophy (PhD)

  - all fields of study, in all countries
- Doctorate of ___ field

  - Some countries:  Austria, Germany, Switzerland and others
  - [Dr-Ing (engineering) etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Science#Austria,_Germany,_and_Switzerland)

### Higher doctorates

- Doctor of Letters (Arts, Humanitites), Doctor of Science etc

  - Field specific doctorate
  - more or less lifetime achievement awards for research.
  - Generally pre-req'd on having a PhD for at least 10 years.
- Dr. habil

  - see [Habilitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation)
  - Most common (but not restricted to) in Germany, Austria, Swizerland.
  - Requires a PhD equivalent

Obviously there will be less people with any given higher doctorate than PhDs since they are a subset of people who have PhDs with in a given field.

### Professional Doctorates

These are doctoral degrees that are required to do a profession.

- Medicine Doctor (MD) i.e. a Doctor of Medicine

  - Every "doctor" in a hospital has at least this.
- Juris Doctor (JD) i,e Doctor of Jurisprudence

  - which in many countries required to be a lawyer
  - by tradition laywers never take the title Dr.

There are a lot of professional doctorate holders.
You've probably seen the thing about PhD holders not using the title Dr on plane tickets because they don't want to be called upon for medical assistance (which they can not provide).

There are probably more PhDs awarded each year than MDs.
But not by a huge margin.

In 2014 the US had 18,078 MDs graduate ([source](https://www.kff.org/other/state-indicator/total-medical-school-graduates/?currentTimeframe=1&sortModel=%7B%22colId%22:%22Location%22,%22sort%22:%22asc%22%7D))
and 54,070 PhDs; of those only about 40,000 were in science and engineering and of those only a very small portion would be in medical science ([source](https://www.nsf.gov/statistics/2016/nsf16300/digest/nsf16300.pdf)).

Also in 2014 the US had 43,832 JDs graduate ([source](https://www.americanbar.org/content/dam/aba/administrative/legal_education_and_admissions_to_the_bar/statistics/2014_law_graduate_employment_data_042915.authcheckdam.pdf)).
This is as compared to only 14,000 nonscience and engineering PhDs; of which only a small portion of which would be in Law.

I posit that for any field with a professional doctorate (I can only think of MD and JD) there will be an order of magnitude more professional doctorates than PhDs in that field.

The only reason PhD numbers are so high vs professional doctorates, is because they are the same degree no matter the field.

Similarly, the only reason they are high compared to Dr.Ing etc is that those degree are only common in certain countries; *and* are field specific.

And vs Higher doctorates: they are prerequed on PhD, and are field specific.

Comment: PhDs do not exist in "all countries" as you listed. In fact, this is contradicted by your next item where "some countries" in fact award "doctorates of [xxx]". For example, I don't really have a "PhD", I have a "doctorat de mathématiques". It's simply easier to say that I have a PhD to English-speaking people. Regarding habilitation, it's not "Germany, Austria, Switzerland and a few other countries". According to Wikipedia, it's at least 28 countries that I'm not going to list. Habilitation is also not a "higher doctorate", by the way. This answer is full of approximations (not to say errors).

Comment: Note also that in some countries PhDs (or doctorates) were introduced in relatively recent times. For instance, in my country, Italy, this degree was introduced only 34 years ago.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  yes, I thought that I was talking in approximations was clear enough, but I guess not. I have editted.   Habilitation is *kinda* a doctorate. Sometimes it gets translated to X doctorate, doesn't it? (I'm not super familar, so do tell me if that bit is ouright wrong). If so then it is a higher doctorate in the sense that it requires a (lower) doctorate before you can start it.

Comment: Getting a PhD typically requires a bachelor degree (or equivalent), and yet nobody thinks of a PhD as a "higher bachelor". Habilitation is a qualification that says "you are fit to direct a research group" (incl PhD students, postdocs...).

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you are saying that I can improve this post by just deleting the "Dr. habil" section?
Comments are for discussing how to improve the post, and I want to understand is that the suggestion you are making?

Comment: And a technical quibble (which doesn't change your point): medical doctors don't always have MD degrees. In the UK, at least, medicine is an _undergraduate_ degree (unlike the US, where it's a graduate course), and newly qualified medics will typically have a pair of bachelors' degrees ([MBChB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Medicine,_Bachelor_of_Surgery)). Thus most 'doctors' (know where your tonsils are) aren't 'doctors' (with a doctorate). MDs are the minority who have _also_ done medical research (‘PhD in medicine’) and who are thus real doctors as well as proper doctors (!).

Comment: I have a French "doctorat en informatique", which was found to be equivalent to a PhD in the Canadian system... A rose called by another name and all that...

Comment: Since you're asking me to be more direct: my "suggestion" is that your answer contains several errors/approximations, and that the correct information it contains is already contained in the other answers.

Comment: The doctorate-vs.-habilitation issue is further confused by the circumstance that at one time (perhaps still now but I don't have recent information), the Russian (at that time Soviet) system had two degrees of this sort. One, equivalent to a doctorate in the U.S. or Germany, had a name that sounded like "candidate". The other, equivalent to a German habilitation, had a name that sounded like "doctor".

Answer (score 11):

In one's early education, especially in more traditional contexts, learning involved *X* being true because the teacher said so.  Don't question the teacher; just make sure that you know *X*.  It was all about memorization ([rote learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rote_learning)).

This would start to change when a student would reach the highest levels of education, at which point they'd be able to argue and contribute their own understanding.  So instead of focusing on rote learning, a student would have to demonstrate their ability to think and engage in [critique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputation) of their field ([scholasticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholasticism)).  This is, successful students would become philosophers of their field rather than simple repositories of memorized facts.

Education's become increasingly [liberal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_arts_education) with a shift from rote learning toward critical thinking, but there's still a semblance of that early expectation that pre-Ph.D. students are supposed to memorize what's being taught while a Ph.D. would symbolize one's ability to go beyond that.

---

#### Historical background

Academics used to be folks who participated in [medieval universities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_university).  There was a heavy religious flavoring to academia compared to today's more secular settings, but it was still general academia nonetheless.

A lot of stuff came from this time.  For example, on graduation when you dress up like Harry Potter, it's because that's how [these guys used to dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Meeting_of_doctors_at_the_university_of_Paris.jpg).

Anyway, so this is where the Bachelor's/Master's/doctorate thing came from:

> #### Course of study
>
> University studies took six years for a Master of Arts degree (a Bachelor of Arts degree was awarded after completing the third or fourth year). Studies for this were organized by the faculty of arts, where the seven liberal arts were taught: arithmetic, geometry, astronomy, music theory, grammar, logic, and rhetoric. All instruction was given in Latin and students were expected to converse in that language. The trivium comprised the three subjects that were taught first: grammar, logic, and rhetoric. These three subjects were the most important of the seven liberal arts for medieval students. The curriculum came also to include the three Aristotelian philosophies: physics, metaphysics and moral philosophy.
>
> -["Medieval university"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_university), Wikpiedia [links and citations omitted]

And that stuff was a lot of the rote learning, before one was a proper doctor.

After that, one'd go into the realm of philosophy, becoming a more critical thinker ([scholar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholasticism)):

> Once a Master of Arts degree had been conferred, the student could leave the university or pursue further studies in one of the higher faculties, law, medicine, or theology, the last one being the most prestigious. A popular textbook for theological study was called the Sentences (*Quattuor libri sententiarum*) of Peter Lombard; theology students as well as masters were required to write extensive commentaries on this text as part of their curriculum.[citation needed] Studies in the higher faculties could take up to twelve years for a master's degree or doctorate (initially the two were synonymous), though again a bachelor's and a licentiate's degree could be awarded along the way.
>
> -["Medieval university"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_university), Wikpiedia [links and citations omitted]

This system was already established by the time "*science*" started to be recognized in a more modern sense.  At that time, it was still just Philosophy, or more specifically "[*Natural Philosophy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_philosophy)".

So, to be a "*doctor of philosophy*" is literally just that - to be a scholar of philosophy who's gone beyond the intro years of rote memorization to the point where they can engage in scholarly critique of their field.

---

#### Ph.D.'s as further Master's degrees

In the historical context in which these degrees were named, the human knowledge pool was way, way smaller.  It was a drop compared to today's oceans.  And so, the prospect of learning much of the human knowledge pool was far more reasonable, if many'd still have regarded it as challenging.

Today, a lot of Ph.D.'s are awarded to students who probably don't quite get the whole philosophy-of-their-field thing.  That seems to be a natural consequence of there being a lot more one can learn before reaching the point of critique and abstraction.

So, today, a Ph.D. *can* be something like a fancy Master's degree.  For example, one can basically get a Master's in Chemistry, then do a bunch of lab work to test something out, and get a Ph.D. for that (experimental chemistry).

In principle, we might argue that there's some need for revision to the academic credentialing system to better capture its modern reality.  And we've actually kinda done that already - as noted in the Wikipedia link above, a Master's and doctorate used to be the same thing; they got more separated in part due to the human knowledge pool growing and more ranks being needed to account for it.  But that'd be a different topic.

For the purposes of this question, a Ph.D. got its name in the scholarly days when academics were basically those who learned their field and then engaged in scholarly critique of it.  And today, the name's kinda a historical artifact.

---

#### Further reading

I found a neat paper that discusses the evolution of doctoral conference since the scholarly days:

- ["*Hora Est!: On Dissertations*"](http://www.ascleiden.nl/Pdf/horaestklein.pdf), 2005.

This document's a look at what scholastics/academics had to do to be recognized as a doctor.  And while the title specifies "*On Dissertations*", it notes:

> Less than a century ago a dissertation was not always required to obtain a doctorate. Successfully defending a number of theses sufficed.  [-page 7]

Other interesting factoids:

- Apparently dissertations used to be more about disputing (critique) points, written up as a [disputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disputation).  This contrasts with the modern description of a PhD being about adding to the human knowledge pool.
- It seems like prior academia was far more concerned with religion than modern academia.  Early academics seem to have been something like clergy.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, he is asking why are phd popular degrees among other doctoral degrees.

Comment: @HermanToothroth Was primarily responding to the **"_For nearly all of my life, i thought a phd was simply a doctorate, and i didn't know that it had anything to do with philosophy._"** part by explaining the connection between a PhD and Philosophy.  Ultimately it's just a name that had historical grounding.  After its historical inception, the name's just stuck around.

Comment: @HermanToothroth If I understand correctly, to put it another way, this answer is saying that PhD's are the most common doctoral degrees simply because "PhD" was the term most commonly chosen for degrees at that level. And it also gives a justification for why the designation "PhD" was chosen so often, at least in older times.

Comment: This answer is actually wrong: PhDs originally did not entail original research at all, just lengthy scholarship and examination. The title comes literally from the meaning of *philosophia*-- love of wisdom. You were a doctor of *philosophia* because back then there was no distinction between e.g. biology, mathematics, astronomy... If you were smart and we're good at it, you could work in the field. Even today, e.g. physics PhDs can and do work in e.g. computer science.

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but [my answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/101210/50609) explains the historical precedent behind the name *philosophiae doctor* from the history of *philosophia*.

Comment: So an S.J.D is a doctoral degree but a J.D. is not?  This conversation seems entirely pedantic.

Comment: @Nat the scope of [your original answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/revisions/101190/1) is entirely different to that of [your current answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/101190/50609).

Comment: @Nat honestly, I find this whole question a hot mess and wish I hadn't partaken in it.

Comment: @errantlinguist Ya know, reading about this topic and its popular perceptions has been a lot of fun.  Academia's got quite a history following from ancient times, shaping what it is today, though there seems to be little understanding of it online.  I'm glad that you did opt to participate; I may've had a bit of fun with the comments, but your answer provides a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 6):

The title *philosophiae doctor* is a remnant from a time when there were no "degree requirements" for jobs and there was not a myriad of different sub-fields: the title "doctor of philosophy" comes from the Greek *philosophia*, literally "love of wisdom". In other words, doctors of "[philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Philosophy&oldid=815419363#Introduction)" were originally much more "free" in what they could and did contribute to intellectually, which is more of an artifact of how far we've progressed in terms of research between now and then than anything else (cf. [Wikipedia for a good overview of university structure from Medieval times onwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Doctor_of_Philosophy&oldid=817234427#History)).

This is shown by the great number of [polymaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath) in the past in relation to now, including but in no way limited to

- Aristotle (384–322 BC),
- Archimedes (c.287–c.212 BC)
- Ptolemy (90–168 AD)
- Jābir ibn Hayyān (Geber) (721–815)
- Ibn Hazm al-Andalusi (994–1064)
- Hildegard von Bingen (1098–1179)
- Leon Battista Alberti (1404–1472)
- Leonardo da Vinci (1452–1519)
- Copernicus (1473–1543)
- Matrakçı Nasuh (1480–c.1564)
- Akbar the Great (1542–1605)
- Isaac Newton (1643–1727)
- Gottfried Leibniz (1646–1716)
- Benjamin Franklin (1706–1790)
- Mikhail Lomonosov (1711–1765)
- David Hume (1711–1776)

(cf. [John Chiappone's *Intro to Humanities* site](http://www.johnchiappone.com/polymaths.html) for many more)

There are many more people with higher degrees now per capita than there were back then, so there should theoretically be *more* polymaths now, but the state of the art has progressed to a level that staying cutting-edge in many fields at once is now much harder. However, even now, people who earned their PhD in one field can and often do go on to contribute to other fields, thus meaning that the spirit of the *doctor philosophiae* is still alive.

Xkcd made [a comic of a very old joke which illustrates this well](https://xkcd.com/435/), but the joke as I know it repeats "*A* is just applied *B*" until it terminates at something like

1. Mathematics is just applied logic, and
2. logic is just applied **philosophy**.

Being someone with a philosophy-leaning background myself, I'd say the author stopped at mathematics because he's a mathematician (it turns out he's a physicist with a sense of humor good enough to be make fun of himself!).

### Origins of the PhD title and its spread

The PhD title originated in Germany as a comprehensive title not specific to any field and was popularized by Americans who studied there and brought the title back to the US. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Doctor_of_Philosophy&oldid=817234427#Educational_reforms_in_Germany):

> This situation changed in the early 19th century through the educational reforms in Germany, most strongly embodied in the model of the University of Berlin, founded and controlled by the Prussian government in 1810. The arts faculty, which in Germany was labelled the faculty of philosophy, started demanding contributions to research,[15] attested by a dissertation, for the award of their final degree, which was labelled Doctor of Philosophy (abbreviated as Ph.D.)—originally this was just the German equivalent of the Master of Arts degree. Whereas in the Middle Ages the arts faculty had a set curriculum, based upon the trivium and the quadrivium, by the 19th century it had come to house all the courses of study in subjects now commonly referred to as sciences and humanities.[16] Professors across the humanities and sciences focused on their advanced research.[17] Practically all the funding came from the central government, and it could be cut off if the professor was politically unacceptable.[relevant? – discuss][18]
>
> These reforms proved extremely successful, and fairly quickly the German universities started attracting foreign students, notably from the United States. The American students would go to Germany to obtain a PhD after having studied for a bachelor's degrees at an American college. So influential was this practice that it was imported to the United States, where in 1861 Yale University started granting the PhD degree to younger students who, after having obtained the bachelor's degree, had completed a prescribed course of graduate study and successfully defended a thesis or dissertation containing original research in science or in the humanities.[19] In Germany, the name of the doctorate was adapted after the philosophy faculty started being split up − e.g. Dr. rer. nat. for doctorates in the faculty of natural sciences − but in most of the English-speaking world the name "Doctor of Philosophy" was retained for research doctorates in all disciplines.
>
> The PhD degree and similar awards spread across Europe in the 19th and early 20th centuries. The degree was introduced in France in 1808, replacing diplomas as the highest academic degree; into Russia in 1819, when the Doktor Nauk degree, roughly equivalent to a PhD, gradually started replacing the specialist diploma, roughly equivalent to the MA, as the highest academic degree; and in Italy in 1927, when PhDs gradually started replacing the Laurea as the highest academic degree.[citation needed]

Despite specialist terminal degrees appearing in other countries, this never gained much traction in the US and to a lesser extent in other parts of the Anglosphere. Additionally, in the Anglosphere (especially in the US), the ideal of greater education as being truly comprehensive in this manner seems to remain stronger than in e.g. continental Europe, with the tradition of [liberal arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_arts_education) still being very strong there while being relatively uncommon in higher levels of education in continental Europe. This **could** explain how the modern notion of the single title "PhD" as a terminal research degree [seems to have spread from the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Doctor_of_Philosophy&oldid=817234427#History_in_the_United_States): Many universities outside the Anglosphere which previously offered terminal degrees other than the PhD are now offering them as a trend of the times and increased internationalization, thus explaining some of the perceived convergence towards the PhD as a single terminal degree even outside of the Anglosphere.

Comment: The author is a physicist, not a mathematician.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks; physicist also makes a lot of sense.

Comment: This answer is pure speculation with little actual information, except a long and pointless list of "polymaths". I would need some actual evidence to believe that the fact that a PhD is the US degree for most research doctorates has something to do with the liberal arts tradition. PhD education in the US is narrowly focused and has no liberal arts element to it. Even breadth requirements in PhD programs are limited to the field of study.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I supplied a huge amount of links which you can read about; What "actual evidence" do you need if that is not enough for you?

Moreover, what is your knowledge of higher education in the US? is your specialization in the [history of education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_higher_education_in_the_United_States)?

Comment: @SashoNikolov I now added explicit passages from Wikipedia illustrating the connection between philosophy, the liberal arts and the modern PhD title. On the linked Wikipedia pages you will find many bibliographic references to books which explain history much better than I can do.

Comment: I still see **nothing** here that supports your assertion that the PhD being common in the US has something to do with the US liberal arts tradition. I have a liberal arts education and a PhD from US universities and currently the two have very different cultures. I am indeed not a historian so maybe there is truth to your claim of a link but nothing in this lengthy quote supports that. Rather, it shows the origin of the title in the German tradition.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I unfortunately cannot and will not write a thesis connecting all the dots between a historical tradition of liberal arts to the name of the PhD (I'm sure some actually have done, or at least a book or article). However, the simple fact that I work with PhDs in psychology, neuroscience, computer science, physics and mathematics every day on the same topic is empirical proof that research can be multidisciplinary. As shown, as an artifact of history, the "older" title of PhD ironically reflects this more accurately than specialized degree titles do.

Comment: @SashoNikolov "The arts faculty, which in Germany was labelled the faculty of philosophy" > philosophy back then encompassed much of what we call "liberal arts" now and even more (this requires the huge amounts of reading/writing I don't have time to write out) > Americans get PhDs from German arts/philosophy departments > Americans popularize and refine PhD-granting programs. The fact that a **modern** PhD **program** is very specialized has **nothing** to do with the name, and I **never** suggested it. Originally, they were **very** different to what they are now. That is the point.

Comment: Ok, both the title PhD and US liberal arts education can be traced back to the faculties of philosophy in Germany. But your last paragraph strongly suggests that the following two facts are related: (i) liberal arts education is *still strong* (in the present) in the US, and not in Europe; (ii) in the US doctoral degrees never differentiated, while in Europe they did. I don't see evidence of a link between (i) and (ii). If you cannot provide any, why are you stating (i)?

Comment: @SashoNikolov fair enough, that is indeed my personal speculation based on my understanding of history and also of the history of education in the US. I'm sure people smarter than myself have written stuff about it, but I can't "prove" a link between them or cite proof. Thank you for being open enough to consider my argument, though. I edited the answer to make my own conjecture a bit easier to spot.

Comment: I guess the German style is that if you are in the Faculty of X, you get a [degree] of X. At some point, X happened to be philosophy. Americans copied the title, but because it was not connected to the organizational structure, they kept it regardless of organizational changes. (We Finns kept the Faculty of Philosophy alive for ceremonial purposes, and the literal translations of our degrees are still PhD and MPhil.)

Comment: @Nat the scope of [your original answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/revisions/101190/1) is entirely different to that of [your current answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/101190/50609).

Answer (score 2):

A Ph.D. refers to an *academic* doctorate.  Which means it is awarded upon completing a body of *original research* in recognition of such completion.   *Professional* doctorate degrees -- MD, JD, DMD, DDS, DO, DC, Psy. D., Pharm.D (and I am borrowing this list from one of the other answers to this question) -- are awarded in recognition of attaining a high level of professional training in those disciplines.

Incidentally, "philosophy" used to refer to all studies which we call *academic* today.  So the title "Philosophy Doctor" stems from those times.

BTW, there is a number of people with double titles MD,Ph.D and DDS,Ph.D.  These indicate both academic research credentials and clinical training credentials.  Presumably, a Ph.D. (in one of life sciences) could be received without ever seeing a human patient.  Whereas an MD is more patient-oriented.